# How to put a footer on bottom using css?

Tags: html, css, footer

I've a simple web page that contains a `<div>` on background (a green rectangle on background) and a second `<div>` that is the "body" it contains paragraphs, table etc

And on bottom I need to to put a simple footer containing juste copyrights and some socials networks buttons. The problem is : the footer is not on bottom, there is a space under the footer, how to avoid this please ?

See my simple code please

On jsfiddle is better (to see the space under the footer) see [here please](https://jsfiddle.net/pitmit/c2dkdmn6/)

```css
.bg-green{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
}

.content{
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  margin:-50px auto;
  background-color:gold;
  text-align:center;
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  height:65px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-green">
</div>
<div class="content">
this is the "body" of my page (kind of a wrapper) it needs to be like this (with negative margin top)
</div>

<footer>this is the footer</footer>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to remove default `margin` of `body`.

Set in css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c2dkdmn6/1/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.bg-green{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
}

.content{
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  margin: -50px auto;
  background-color:gold;
  text-align:center;
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  height:65px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-green">
</div>
<div class="content">
this is the "body" of my page (kind of a wrapper) it needs to be like this (with negative margin top)
</div>

<footer>this is the footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

For best practice always set body and html `0 margin` and `0 padding`.

```
body,html{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.bg-green{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
}

.content{
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  margin:10px auto;
  background-color:gold;
  text-align:center;
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  height:65px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-green">
</div>
<div class="content">
this is the "body" of my page (kind of a wrapper) it needs to be like this (with negative margin top)
</div>

<footer>this is the footer</footer>
```

Modify content css:

```
.content{
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  margin:10px auto;
  background-color:gold;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .footer

```
margin-top:50px;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to stick your footer to the bottom?

**Clear** the paddings and margins by:

```
html, body {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

then

```
footer{
   width:100%;
   height:65px;
   background-color:red;
   opacity:0.5;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
}
```

Working [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lazfguk/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the min height of body to 100% and set position to absolute.

```css
.bg-green{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
}

.content{
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  margin:-50px auto;
  background-color:gold;
  text-align:center;
}

html, body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html{
  height: 100%;
}    
body{      
  min-height: 100%;
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  height:65px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:0.5;
  position: absolute:
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-green">
</div>
<div class="content">
this is the "body" of my page (kind of a wrapper) it needs to be like this (with negative margin top)
</div>

<footer>this is the footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that case you just need to set the `margin` and `padding` of body tag to 0.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or if your site have margins specified you can only set the bottom margin of body as.

```
body {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bg-green{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
}

.content{
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  margin:-50px auto;
  background-color:gold;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:100px;
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  height:65px;
  margin-top: -65px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:0.5;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-green">
</div>
<div class="content">
this is the "body" of my page (kind of a wrapper) it needs to be like this (with negative margin top)
</div>

<footer>this is the footer</footer>
```

You can fix footer at bottom by `position: absolute;`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2dkdmn6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;bottom: 0;` Style in **footer class**

```
 footer
   {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

Click Here [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/2dqvg7kt/)